# Wrong row count in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem when counting specific rows in datagridview.
I am counting only rows where a checkbox value of one of the cells is true.

The Code is:

```
            int checkedRowCount = 0;

        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls";
        sfd.FilterIndex = 0;
        sfd.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (sfd.FileName != "")
            {
                Excel.Application xlApp;
                Excel.Workbook xlWB;
                Excel.Worksheet xlWS;

                xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                xlWS = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWB.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

Parallel.ForEach(dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>(), row =>
                {

                    DataGridViewCell cbCell = row.Cells[6];
                    if (!(cbCell.Value is DBNull))
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(cbCell.Value) == true)
                        {
                            checkedRowCount++;

                            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                            {
                                xlWS.Cells[checkedRowCount, i + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                xlWB.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                xlWB.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                xlApp.Quit();

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWS);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWB);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            }
        }
```

The reason I using a different row count for the current row(instead of row.Index) is because I am writing the  checked rows(checked checkbox in dgv) in excel file.

The output is the total rows instead of just the current one.

The output of that is:

```
15
15
15
15
```

And it should be:

```
1
2
3
...
```

I made a different project just to test that and its working fine...

Any suggestions?

Best Regards

Comment: You are checking the same thing every time, resulting in the same number 15.  `DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[6];`  you have 6 hard coded?

Comment: `if (Convert.ToBoolean(cell.Value) == true)`is weird.

Comment: This is the row.Cells[6] is the 6th column from dgv. I am checking that column because it contains the actual checkboxes.

Comment: You don't need to iterate the columns. That is what is repeating the same value several times.

Comment: Remove `for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)`

Comment: @DragandDrop I know.. Any other ideas how to check if the checkbox is true or false ? The column with checkboxes is added programmatically to the datatable with Columns.Add

Comment: @DragandDrop I cannot remove that because for the current row I have to check the columns and get the value to write into the excel file.

Comment: My understanding of your requiremnt was : Foreach row, if the 7th column is checked I add an item to the listbox. I don't understand the :  Foreach row, if the 7th column is checked, **foreach column , add item to list box**

Comment: @DragandDrop DGV source is a DataTable. The DataTable is populated from a database. The last column(the one with checkboxes) is added programmatically. I am looping for each row in dgv to check if the checkbox in 7th column is selected or not, if the checkbox is selected I am increasing an integer. The reason I am increasing that integer is because when I'm writing the excel file that integer represents the rows in that excel file. If I use row.Index instead of that int there will be empty rows in the excel file. (currently just testing with listbox)

Comment: @DragandDrop I am going through the columns is because I need the values for the current row.

Comment: Thats what you want. But you are currently adding the same number to list box depending on Column .count -1 .

Comment: I don't see any acces to row.Cells[0]; or  row.Cells[1]; or row.Cells[2]; etc

Comment: @DragandDrop maybe because of this missing piece of code you are having troubles understanding: 

`xlWS.Cells[checkedRowCount, i + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[i].Value.ToString();`

Comment: Ok, Is the `listBox1.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                                    {
                                        listBox1.Items.Add(checkedRowCount);
                                    }));` had to be in the for each column loop ?

Comment: @DragandDrop I am using a listbox just to print the output of the checked rows.

Comment: I'm not sure you get my point.. Move that line 2 row South in your code. You are still talking about row, checked row. but you do that in column loop not in row loop. Get in the lower loop should be enought.

Comment: I am checking for a checked row in the row loop and if its checked then increase the int and go through the column loop. Inside that column loop add the values into excel cells.

Comment: There is a communication issue. Check my answer see it it helps. May you comment why so other has a chance of getting better understanding of your question.

Comment: @DragandDrop I updated the code, the exact it should be when creating the excel file, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding :

```
int checkedRowCount = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(
    dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    , row =>
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[6];

        if (!(cell.Value is DBNull))
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(cell.Value))
            {
                checkedRowCount++;

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    // Works on The other column value    
                    // Add the value to excel here   
                }

                // Add to the ListBox only once per Row, Instead of Once per Column per Row
                listBox1.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(checkedRowCount);
                }));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I need it once per columns, per row because I need all the values from dgv cells to be printed in the excel file. I'll edit the exact code with the excel code.